# How can fsck be so fast?

Tags: filesystems, ssd, fsck

Is it normal, that fsck on an SSD takes a second or two? I am on Linux Mint 17.3 and I called

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

**EDIT:** ext4 filesystem

Comment: What filesystem are you using? It's possible that a journaling filesystem will immediately go "oh, the journal looks ok, I didn't lose any transactions, all is well"

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz ext4

Comment: Did you reboot after running that `touch`? You're aware that forces an fsck on the next boot, correct?

Comment: @derobert yes I did

Comment: @don_crissti if you're familiar with fsck times on SSDs, please post an answer—do not use comments to answer the question.

Comment: @derobert - I've been experiencing about the same times when forcing a `fsck` on an otherwise consistent `ext4`: less than 2 seconds. Not sure how to put that in an answer (sounds OK as a comment imo but really dumb as an answer so I'll leave it as a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual answer is, that the command on Linux Mint does not work as proven in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/126755), section:

> **These two options did NOT work**: Adding the `/forcefsck` empty file with

---

Please refer to the [mentioned answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400927/126755) for more information, for instance as to how to actually force a file system check.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of fsck, "normal"

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdx
```

and "full"

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sdx
```

Your computer runs a normal fsck at every boot, which is really fast. fsck -f obviously takes longer, but in newer filesystems (ext4) it's still quite fast. With SSD might as well double that, and your fsck -f shouldn't take long at all.

Warning: Never run those codes on a mounted disk. It can cause severe filesystem corruption.

Comment: Not really, ext4 only has one type of fsck. It just tracks internally if it is needed—without `-f`, it only does an fsck if it thinks one is needed. With `-f`, it does one regardless. Refer to `man e2fsck`.

Comment: I've found fsck -f -t takes longer than fsck -t consistently, but I guess that's just anecdotal

Comment: that's probably because without -f it didn't actually run an fsck. Not entirely sure of the behavior of -t as I've never run fsck time trials... You can use tune2fs to set the fsck needed flag, BTW.

Comment: freaking ubuntu forums misled me. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680978 I wanted to edit the "f-ck" to fsck but apparently my time for that  ran out. well I suppose that's good for everyone since that joke is old and tired.

Comment: I can't believe 2 things: a) on kubuntu 16, `man fsck` DOES NOT have the `-f` option. Is it a hidden one??, WTF, how idiotic. Assume you have a half trusted device and you want to check it when you want, why can't linux allow you to do it. 2) Why this GREAT answer had -2 points is beyond me!